# Mocking $location service in angular unit test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am new to developing in angular, and am trying to learn how to test angular controllers. The controller I am testing uses $location.seach().something. I looked at the docs for $location, but don't quickly see how I am supposed to mock this in karma/jasmine.

The controller:

```
rmtg.controller('ErrorCtrl', ['Session', '$location', '$routeParams', '$scope', '$window',
    function(Session, $location, $routeParams, $scope, $window) {
        console.log('ErrorCtrl(%o, %o, %o)', $location.path(), $location.search(), $routeParams);

        $scope.status = $location.search().status;
        $scope.message = $location.search().message;

        $scope.isAuthorized = (typeof(Session.auth) === 'object');

        $scope.signin = function() {
             $window.location = '/signin/#/' + $routeParams.origin + (Session.auth ? '?email=' + Session.auth.email : '');
        };
     }]);
```

My current spec attempt:

```
'user strict';

describe('Testing the errorCtrl controller', function(){
    beforeEach(module("rmtg"));

    var errorCtrl, scope;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope){
        scope = $rootScope;
        errorCtrl = $controller("ErrorCtrl", {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));


   it('$scope.status should be set to 404 when location is set to 404', function(){
        //set the $location.search values so that the scope is correct
        $location.search('status', '404');
        expect(scope.status).toBe('404');
    });
});
```

And the current error message:
Testing the errorCtrl controller $scope.status should be set to 404 when location is set to 404 FAILED
    Expected undefined to be '404'.
        at Object. (/Users/adamremeeting/git/mrp-www/app/tests/example.js:20:24)

I'd also really appreciate links to resources on tdd with angular 1.5 and how I mock and stub correctly.

**Edit After Answer**

So I updated the test as per user2341963 suggestions, and did my best to look through his plunker example, but still don't have a passing test.

the current spec (controller has not changed from above)

```
'user strict';

describe('ErrorCtrl', function(){
    beforeEach(module("rmtg"));

    var scope, $location, $controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$location_){
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $location = _$location_
        $controller = $_controller_;
    }));


    describe('$scope.status', function(){
        it('should set status to 404', function(){
            //set the $location.search values so that the scope is correct
            $location.search('status', '404');
            //init controller
            $controller('ErrorCtrl', {
                $scope: scope,
                $location: $location
            });
            expect(scope.status).toBe('404');
        });
    });
});
```

But I am getting an error now that $*controller* is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting `undefined` in your test because you are not setting `$location`  anywhere.

Based on your controller, the search parameters must be set before the controller is initialised. See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GLt56dpxFUNpR4uAu0qd?p=preview) for full example.

```
describe('testApp', function() {

  describe('MainCtrl', function() {
    var scope, $location, $controller;

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_, _$location_) {
      scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
      $location = _$location_;
      $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    it('should set status to 404', function() {
      // Set the status first ...
      $location.search('status', '404');      
      // Then initialise the controller
      $controller('MainCtrl', {
        $scope: scope,
        $location: $location
      });
      expect(scope.status).toBe('404');
    });
  });
});
```

As for resources, so far I've found the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing) are good enough.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I am now getting an error $_controller_ is not defined. So where was I supposed to define the underscored version?

Comment: Never mind, it was a typo on my part, I am not used to the syntax for the injector.